# Sorting numbers using Java Collections.sort()

Tags: java, performance, sorting, collections

Input is a file containing numbers in this format:

> ```
> 1.2 3 5.1 2 7 4 6
> 5 2 9.22 1 0.0 4 3
> ```

I am doing the sorting in the simplest way, using `Collections.sort` method. The running code is as follows:

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SortedNumbers {

    public static Double integerFromString(String str) {
        return Double.valueOf(str.substring(0, str.length()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
         String fileName = "";

        //scanner to read the file
        Scanner fileInput = null;

        List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();

        //first check if there is an input parameter
        if(args.length > 0) {
            fileName = args[0];
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("No file specified");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //connect to the file
        FileReader file = new FileReader (fileName);
        fileInput = new Scanner(file);

        //start reading from the file, store all the lines in the list
        while(fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
            String num = fileInput.nextLine();
            temps.add(num);
        }

        //close the scanner
        fileInput.close();

        //convert the list into array of strings
        String[] str = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

        /**
         * for each string in str array, split it using space as the delimiter and store the splitted strings in an array,
         * for each string value in the array, convert it into Double and store it in a collection
         * Sort the collection, convert it into String
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            List<Double> num = new LinkedList<Double>();
            String[] arr = str[i].split("\\s");
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
                Double currentNumber = integerFromString(arr[j]);
                num.add(currentNumber);
            }
            Collections.sort(num);
            String sortedNumbers = num.toString();
            int indexOfOpenBracket = sortedNumbers.indexOf("[");
            int indexOfLastBracket = sortedNumbers.lastIndexOf("]");
            System.out.println(sortedNumbers.substring(indexOfOpenBracket+1, indexOfLastBracket));
        }
    }
}
```

I am concerned about the performance, splitting the string and storing it in array, parsing each string from array into double and then adding in the list.  It seems like there could be an efficient way.

Are there any redundant steps in the code which I can avoid?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few improvements I can see, but not really related to performance (though it may run a bit faster anyway).

If the files are small (less than 10Megabytes or so), then the relative performance of different approaches are slight (obviously, you can bork your code, but the IO part will remain about the same). So, it comes down to readability.

For readability, I would recommend using the 'cool' toys in Java7. Consider the following:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(args[0]));
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
    double[] values = new double[parts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        values[i] = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(values);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(values[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());       
}
```

Note the key elements here:

- use [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) classes
- use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for the string concatenation
- use String.split, not a scanner....
- use primitive data structures (arrays of double, not Double)
- that means using Arrays.sort, not Collections.sort

Other things to consider.....

- a method called `integerFromString` ... that returns a `double` is ... confusing.
- using List.toString() and the stripping off the `[` and `]` is backward.

Comment: +1.  I would use something like Iterables.skip(..) instead of the if(i > 0), but overall nice

Answer (score 10):

A few things that @rolfl didn't mention explicitly:

```
public static Double integerFromString(String str) {
    return Double.valueOf(str.substring(0, str.length()));
}
```

This code alone can be significantly improved.

- @rolfl is right that it has a confusing name as it returns a `Double`.
- When you use `str.substring(0, str.length())` you'll get back exactly the same string you started with so simply `str` would be enough.
- There is no need to return the non-primitive `Double`, instead use the method `parseDouble` which returns a primitive `double`. If you are not aware of the differences, [read up about them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

  public static double doubleFromString(String str) {
      return Double.parseDouble(str);
  }

This however makes this method more or less pointless, it would be easier and more clear to use `Double.parseDouble` directly.

---

There is, in my opinion, not much use for the fileName variable. Sure, it can be used to make it more clear what the contents of `args[0]` represent, but you're only using it once. Consider making this change:

```
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("No file specified");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    FileReader file = new FileReader(args[0]);
```

---

I would rather use an `ArrayList` than a `LinkedList` when sorting. They have [some differences in speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist).

---

The variable names `temps` and `str`, `arr` are not very describing. The same goes for several of your other variables. Consider the names `inputLines`, `line`, `splittedLine` instead. `String num` is also a confusing name as it holds the entire line and not only a number, rename to `inputLine` or similar instead (or you could just do `inputLines.add(fileInput.nextLine());` without using a temporary variable).

There is no need to read the input to a list and then convert to an array. You can loop through a List by using a "for-each" loop.

```
for (String line : inputLines) {
    ...
}
```

However, as all you want to do is to process the lines once, there is no need to store it in a list first just to process it later.

Overall, I totally agree with everything @rolfl said, I just wanted to provide these additional comments.

Answer (score 5):

With Java 8 we can actually write this nicely succinct:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Expected: <filename>");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    // The number of times where using the platform default encoding is a good idea
    // is pretty much nil..
    String data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0])), "UTF-8");
    String result = Arrays.stream(data.split("\\s+")).
            mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).
            sorted().
            mapToObj(Double::toString).
            reduce("", (x, y) -> x + y + " ");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Obviously instead of reducing it to a simple string, we could just as easily print it directly:

```
    Arrays.stream(data.split("\\s+")).
            mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).
            sorted().
            forEach(d -> System.out.print(d + " "));
```

The only annoyance is that Java doesn't offer any reduceLeft or similar method, which means we either have to provide one ourselves or live with the fact that there's a trailing space at the end of the output.

The whole thing is almost certainly IO limited, but from a performance point of view we avoid the unnecessary boxing to double *and* it is trivial to parallelize this if we were inclined to do so. So not only is it way more readable, descriptive and shorter, but also potentially more performant as well.

On the other hand this doesn't do an in-place sort which can be problematic in case of a really large file, in which case we'd want to get the array back, sort it the old way and then just print it (which can be done efficiently again using forEach).

**Edit:** Since the idea was to print each line itself sorted we need some small change to make it do that instead:

```
    Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).
            map(line -> line.split("\\s+")).
            map(vals -> Arrays.stream(vals).
                    mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).
                    sorted().
                    mapToObj(Double::toString).
                    collect(Collectors.joining(", "))).
            forEach(System.out::println);
```

which shows one definite advantage of a descriptive approach. The corresponding code to reduce it to an array of Strings instead of printing directly is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I agree that the streams APIU will shorten the code, so you got +1 , but, your code does not do the same as the OP's. The OP sorts the doubles on each line, not merging all the lines together and sorting that.

Comment: @rolfl Ah yes. The nice thing is that it's basically no effort at all to change it to do that instead. So ahem yes that was purely for educational reasons ;)

Comment: As I see it the functional APIs not only shorten the code, but also demonstrate the intent more clearly and make changes way easier because we don't mutate any state. The only change I really had to do was add a second `map` to the code, but I could reuse the `mapToDouble.. reduce` code without any changes. Changing the procedural code to do the opposite would certainly require more changes.

Comment: your code is not putting ", " between the sorted values, and it adds an extra space at the end. While I agree with you that Java8 streams can hep in a number of ways, recommending it blindly as a solution is ... shortsighted. In reality, I believe my version of the code shows the logic a lot more clearly than yours. In fact, your code is more confusing than readable... like, the `x + y + " "` <- if x and y are doubles you will get different results to if they are Doubles or Strings. The Function makes these details hard to see.

Comment: Streams tend to lead to long lines with line-breaks part way through. In your code, you have made this worse by having a nested stream. Nested streams indicate that the source data is not a functional problem, but an iterative one. For at least the outside stream, a loop would be a better solution.

Comment: @rolfl Yeah and that was clearly pointed out - you need a foldLeft for that one (well I said almost arrived in 1958..). And why is the reduce confusing? It clearly states that we map doubles to strings before doing so - "If you change the types involved in an expression something else may happen" is true for every kind of programming style. And if nested streams indicate that a problem is not functional, quite a lot of Haskel and Lisp code will have to be rewritten. But try it and change your code to output everything on one line and see how many changes are necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14847/discussion-between-rolfl-and-voo).